# Stackoverflow error caused by SeekBar and EditText changing one another

Tags: android, android-edittext, stack-overflow, seekbar

So I have a SeekBar set up in conjunction with an EditText of input type number.

I want it to be so that if the user enters a number within a viable range it will change the progress of a the SeekBar. Furthermore; if the user decides that they would rather change by dragging the SeekBar; that will instead change the EditText to the SeekBar's current value.

I receive a stackoverflow trying to implement this and I believe it is because I have both of them using their onChanged listeners. So they are causing infinite changes to eachother.

If that is the case; how would I go about achieving my desired outcome as explained?

Code:

```
s1.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
                            if(progress != Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()))
            et1.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            if(i != Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()))
            s1.setProgress(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
```

Logcat:

```
    03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5867)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5765)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6304)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3567)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$1.onProgressChanged(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.updateProgress(SeekArc.java:425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.setProgress(SeekArc.java:454)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$5.afterTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:116)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7119)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3574)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$1.onProgressChanged(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.updateProgress(SeekArc.java:425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.setProgress(SeekArc.java:454)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$5.afterTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:116)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7119)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3574)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$1.onProgressChanged(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.updateProgress(SeekArc.java:425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.setProgress(SeekArc.java:454)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$5.afterTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:116)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7119)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3574)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$1.onProgressChanged(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.updateProgress(SeekArc.java:425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.setProgress(SeekArc.java:454)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$5.afterTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:116)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7119)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3574)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$1.onProgressChanged(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.updateProgress(SeekArc.java:425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.setProgress(SeekArc.java:454)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$5.afterTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:116)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7119)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3574)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$1.onProgressChanged(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.updateProgress(SeekArc.java:425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.setProgress(SeekArc.java:454)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at com.nanospark.upcdemo.HomeFragment$5.afterTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:116)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7119)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3574)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-18 14:38:59.104: E/AndroidRuntime(2894):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80
```

Comment: P.S. SeekArc is the exact same in functionality as SeekBar. It's just curved.

Comment: A simple idea might be to not notify the other if the value you've been changed to is the value you are already at.  One could perhaps imagine obscure cases where that would fail (some kind of race condition toggling between two values?).

Comment: I have attempted that as in my latest additions and it still causes the overflow; check out my conditions on my latest change

Comment: Add logging to your decisioning logic and that should reveal why it is failing to break the circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress, boolean fromUser)` you have a `fromUser` variable. Don't set text on your `EditText` if the user wasn't the one that scrubbed your SeekBar/Arc (the text can already be assumed to be correct as it initiated the chain of events...)

In your listener:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if(fromUser && progress != Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString())) {
        et1.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked; thank you @Tonithy. I was stupid to not use the fromUser boolean.

Comment: @Turkajo It happens, lol. In a perfect world, everyone would read the documentation, but definitely check out the whole method signature.

Answer (score 5):

In afterTextChanged - before you set the progress , disable the seek bar listener setOnSeekArcChangeListener(null) . and then add the listener again.

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        s1.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(null);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        if(i>=0 && i<100)
        s1.setProgress(i);
        s1.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(mSeekListener);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal beceause when you change your SeekBar value, you change your EditText value in the seekbar listener (et1.setText(String.valueOf(progress));) so the EditText Listener was called AND when you change your EditText value  (on the SeekBar listener), you change the SeekBar value in the EditText's Listener then you create an kind of inifinity loop.

Comment: This is what I had already stated in my problem. This is not an answer. While I appreciate the feedback please refrain from answering if you did not fully read the question.

Comment: @Tukajo - in fairness to Francois, it's wasn't entirely clear that you understood your problem until you edited the title.